# Calculate number of positive and negative string for each word in a list

Tags: python, list

I am new in python and hope you could help me solve this problem and I am using python 3.4.

I have a list that contain word,either positive or negative, and it's frequency

This is the original list:

```
`finalSentiment = [('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'),  ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'),  ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('left', 'negative'), ('pay', 'negative'), ('pay', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('befo', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('radical', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('tcot', 'negative'), ('mt', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('loony', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('right', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('tanker', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('people', 'negative'), ('sadly', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('morons', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('oil', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('get', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('account', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('pirates', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('flag', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('like', 'negative'), ('day', 'negative'), ('day', 'negative'), ('day', 'negative'), ('day', 'negative'), ('day', 'negative'), ('day', 'negative'), ('day', 'negative'), ('day', 'negative'), ('day', 'negative'), ('malaysia', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('one', 'negative'), ('got', 'negative'), ('got', 'negative'), ('got', 'negative'), ('got', 'negative'), ('got', 'negative'), ('got', 'negative'), ('got', 'negative'), ('long', 'negative'), ('long', 'negative'), ('long', 'negative'), ('long', 'negative'), ('long', 'negative'), ('long', 'negative'), ('long', 'negative'), ('none', 'positive'), ('look', 'positive'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('time', 'negative'), ('fathers', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('terrorist', 'negative'), ('know', 'negative'), ('know', 'negative'), ('know', 'negative'), ('know', 'negative'), ('know', 'negative'), ('know', 'negative'), ('know', 'negative'), ('know', 'negative'), ('know', 'negative'), ('driver', 'negative'), ('driver', 'negative'), ('driver', 'negative'), ('driver', 'negative'), ('driver', 'negative'), ('driver', 'negative'), ('angry', 'negative'), ('angry', 'negative'), ('angry', 'negative'), ('angry', 'negative'), ('angry', 'negative'), ('angry', 'negative'), ('angry', 'negative'), ('angry', 'negative'), ('angry', 'negative'), ('live', 'negative'), ('live', 'negative'), ('live', 'negative'), ('dem', 'negative'), ('dem', 'negative'), ('dem', 'negative'), ('dem', 'negative'), ('dem', 'negative'), ('dem', 'negative'), ('dem', 'negative')]`
```

What i am trying to do is to calculate number of positive and negative for each word from the list that I have.
So that if the number of negative is higher, the word is negative.
Then I can come out with a new list like: 
eg: `newList = [('hijacked','negative'),('left','negative'), . . .]`

a) I try using the `num = Count(finalSentiment).most_common()[:50]` function and came out with the new  list as below.

```
num =  [(('hijacked', 'negative'), 302), (('left', 'negative'), 88), (('one', 'negative'), 79), (('befo', 'negative'), 72), (('radical', 'negative'), 70), (('tcot', 'negative'), 70), (('tanker', 'negative'), 55), (('like', 'negative'), 47), (('right', 'negative'), 36), (('oil', 'negative'), 26), (('hijacked', 'positive'), 22), (('pirates', 'negative'), 21), (('people', 'negative'), 21), (('terrorist', 'negative'), 21), (('loony', 'negative'), 18), (('morons', 'negative'), 18), (('get', 'negative'), 17), (('account', 'negative'), 12), (('flag', 'negative'), 11), (('time', 'negative'), 10), (('angry', 'negative'), 9), (('like', 'positive'), 8), (('day', 'negative'), 8), (('know', 'negative'), 8), (('dem', 'negative'), 7), (('tanker', 'positive'), 7), (('long', 'negative'), 6), (('left', 'positive'), 6), (('driver', 'negative'), 6), (('one', 'positive'), 6), (('got', 'negative'), 6), (('tcot', 'positive'), 5), (('radical', 'positive'), 5), (('befo', 'positive'), 5), (('pirates', 'positive'), 3), (('live', 'negative'), 3), (('oil', 'positive'), 2), (('time', 'positive'), 2), (('pay', 'negative'), 2), (('none', 'positive'), 1), (('people', 'positive'), 1), (('morons', 'positive'), 1), (('long', 'positive'), 1), (('account', 'positive'), 1), (('mt', 'negative'), 1), (('got', 'positive'), 1), (('day', 'positive'), 1), (('loony', 'positive'), 1), (('know', 'positive'), 1), (('fathers', 'negative'), 1)]
```

What I want to do is to compare the word frequency either positive or negative is higher.
So, if negative is higher I want to create a new list that contain the word and negative.

eg: `[('hijacked','negative'),('left','negative'), . . .]`

Each word will only have either positive or negative in the list.

What I have try to is I try to access each of the item in the list using for loop.

```
for item in num:

        unique_word = item[0]
        temp = unique_word[0]
        temp1 = unique_word[1]
        frequency = item[1]
```

but I cant figure out how to manipulate the data after I access it.

b) I use counter() function and come out with this list:

```
cnt = Counter()
for word in finalSentiment:
    cnt[word] += 1
print(cnt)

Counter({('hijacked', 'negative'): 302, ('left', 'negative'): 88, ('one', 'negative'): 79, ('befo', 'negative'): 72, ('tcot', 'negative'): 70, ('radical', 'negative'): 70, ('tanker', 'negative'): 55, ('like', 'negative'): 47, ('right', 'negative'): 36, ('oil', 'negative'): 26, ('hijacked', 'positive'): 22, ('pirates', 'negative'): 21, ('terrorist', 'negative'): 21, ('people', 'negative'): 21, ('morons', 'negative'): 18, ('loony', 'negative'): 18, ('get', 'negative'): 17, ('account', 'negative'): 12, ('flag', 'negative'): 11, ('time', 'negative'): 10, ('angry', 'negative'): 9, ('like', 'positive'): 8, ('day', 'negative'): 8, ('know', 'negative'): 8, ('dem', 'negative'): 7, ('tanker', 'positive'): 7, ('got', 'negative'): 6, ('left', 'positive'): 6, ('one', 'positive'): 6, ('driver', 'negative'): 6, ('long', 'negative'): 6, ('radical', 'positive'): 5, ('befo', 'positive'): 5, ('tcot', 'positive'): 5, ('pirates', 'positive'): 3, ('live', 'negative'): 3, ('time', 'positive'): 2, ('pay', 'negative'): 2, ('oil', 'positive'): 2, ('mt', 'negative'): 1, ('loony', 'positive'): 1, ('morons', 'positive'): 1, ('long', 'positive'): 1, ('got', 'positive'): 1, ('sadly', 'negative'): 1, ('day', 'positive'): 1, ('none', 'positive'): 1, ('fathers', 'negative'): 1, ('account', 'positive'): 1, ('malaysia', 'negative'): 1, ('right', 'positive'): 1, ('people', 'positive'): 1, ('know', 'positive'): 1, ('look', 'positive'): 1})
```

The problem I have now is how to compare as example the word 'hijacked', the number of negative is higher. So in the new list, 'hijacked' should be 'negative such that: 
eg: newList = `[('hijacked','negative'),('left','negative'), . . .]`

c) OR maybe I should calculate number of positive and negative on my own instead of using the `most_common()` function or `counter()`.
My problem to calculate the number of positive and negative is because there are multiple word in the list. If the word is only 'hijacked' with positive and negative attached to it I think I can solve the problem.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Both answer solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(finalSentiment)

output = [] 
for word in set(w for w, s in finalSentiment):
    if counts.get((word, 'positive'), 0) > counts.get((word, 'negative'), 0):
        output.append((word, 'positive'))
    else:
        output.append((word, 'negative'))
```

Comment: The first solution give me a list like the original list that the same word repeating many time. eg: [('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ('hijacked', 'negative'), ...]. I am trying to make a list with word and positive/negative without the same word repetitive. The second solution give me the same list as the first solution. Somehow both solution have missing words in the list from the original list.

Comment: Oh, ok. I was trying to use the full list to avoid the chance of missing words which only appear as one sentiment and not the other. I wasn't thinking about duplicates. I've edited my answer with one that does the counter, but then steps through the set of words - to hopefully cover all words without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
finalSentiment = [('a','negative'),('a','negative'),('a','positive'),('b','positive')]
cnt = Counter(finalSentiment)
noDups = list(set([x[0] for x in set(finalSentiment)]))
newList =[]
for each in noDups:
    if cnt[(each,'positive')] > cnt[(each,'negative')]:
        newList.append((each,'positive'))
    else:
        newList.append((each,'negative'))
```

`newList`:

```
[('a', 'negative'), ('b', 'positive')]
```